# Best way to structure query for reporting

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I need to create a SSRS summary report which captures a lot of data from many different sources.  The report needs to report on about a dozen summary numbers for 3 different types.  The computations for each number are pretty complex so I definitely want to optimize the overall reporting.

I'm going to call X/Y/Z "Types" and A/B/C/D/E/D "Items"

Example:

```
      X     Y     Z
```

```
A     10    12    14
```

```
B     8     6     11
```

```
C     12    0     99
```

```
D     10    12    14
```

```
E     8     6     11
```

```
F     12    0     99
```

I have the sql to generate each number - a function for each "row" which I just pass X/Y/Z.

My question is how to I gather all the data together to report on it?  I can:

1. Create each data point as a subquery and string them together in one long statement with descriptive column names
2. Union all the data for each type together into a single proc/function, so I would get the 1st & 2nd columns in one result set, 1st & 3rd columns together in another, and 1st and 4th columns in a third.  Then I suppose I could join these together.
3. Generate each data point as a row (i.e. A;X;10) and pivot them all together.

Also am I best off creating a function for each Item, so I call fnA(X) to get 10?  As opposed to just stringing together the SQL in a proc?

I'm reasonably adept at SQL but just getting in to SSRS so I may be missing an easier way to do it.  I'm trying to get all the data in SQL and then use that in SSRS but if I should be doing more in SSRS and less in SQL I'm open to it!

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Have you already tried any of the above approaches yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a cursor to go through and pull each data point for each X/Y/Z type and inserting it into a temp table.  Then I used SSRS to display it in a matrix.  Sort of dirty but it works...

Answer (score 0):

SSRS can easily deal with the data if it's returned from a SQL query in either of these two forms:

```
       X     Y     Z
 A     10    12    14
 B     8     6     11
 C     12    0     99
 D     10    12    14
 E     8     6     11
 F     12    0     99
```

**or**

```
 Item  Type  Value
 A      X     10
 A      Y     12
 A      Z     14
 B      X     8
 B      Y     6
 B      Z     11
 C      X     12
 C      Y     0
...
```

You'll definitely have an easier time in SSRS if this is returned from a single query. There are a few ways to get results from multiple queries, but they aren't as straightforward as working with one query's results.

Then the question becomes what's easier to return from SQL. Sounds like you've got a good handle on some of the options: your answer will depend on your db schema as well as your comfort (or inclination) with different features of SQL.

I'd try a couple of approaches in SSMS: go with whichever gives you the cleanest code or the best performance, if needed.

Comment: I guess it makes sense to just try a few different ways - if I can find the time...  Thanks!